# How to restrict a parameter of python function must be string or a function like lambda expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, the following, the first parameter should be restricted to a string, and the second parameter should be a function. However, this is wrong syntax for both. Anyone can help suggest the correct syntax to impose the type restriction?

```
def GetArg(msg:String, converter:lambda, default):
    print("{}, the default is '{}':".format(msg, default))
    return converter(stdin.readline().strip())
```

It gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/stdin_ext.py", line 4, in <module>
    def GetArg(msg:String, converter, default:String):
NameError: name 'String' is not defined
```

and

```
  File "E:/stdin_ext.py", line 4
    def GetArg(msg:String, converter:lambda, default:String):
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the typing module.

```
from typing import Callable

def get_arg(msg: str, converter: Callable[[str], str], default) -> str:
    print(f"{msg}, the default is '{default}':")
    return converter(stdin.readline().strip())
```

assuming your function `converter` takes a `string` a returns a `string`, and that `get_arg` returns a `string`. Note the code has also been modified to follow python's [naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and uses [`f strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) over older style format strings.

Also note that these `type hints` are just that, *hints*. They are not checked statically or at runtime. Although, certain IDE's will help you ensure they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `str` instead of `String` and [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) instead of lambda:

```
from typing import Callable    

def GetArg(msg:str, converter:Callable, default):
    print("{}, the default is '{}':".format(msg, default))
    return converter(stdin.readline().strip())
```

That is, unless you have a specific class called `String` and you are expecting an argument of its type.

When you write `lambda` you are **defining** a new lambda, not specifying a type for a function, whence the error.

I believe it is also important to point out that types in python are only a useful notation but it does not raise any error by itself, for example I could still call `GetArg(1,2,3)` and don't get any error **just by the type hinting** (of course I would get an error trying to pass an argument to an int afterwards).

Comment: Isn't a [Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable) annotation, e.g. `get_next_item: Callable[[], str]` a better fit?

Comment: `Callable[[], str]` implies that the function takes no arguments and returns a string. This is not the case, as the function clearly takes a string. @RachSharp was just giving an example.